# Adding to struct from a loop (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, for-loop, struct

So I'm using the code below but am getting an error when trying to call the text from a line in the struct.

```
struct lines
{
    LPCSTR text;
    int mInt;
};


for (int n = 0; n < lineCount - 1; ++n) {
        vector<lines> sub;
        lines lineData;
        LPCSTR onlinePlayerName = (LPCSTR)PLAYER::GET_PLAYER_NAME((Player)(n));
        int onlinePlayerPed = PLAYER::GET_PLAYER_PED(n);

        //lines(n) = struct( onlinePlayerName, onlinePlayerPed );
        sub.push_back(lines());
        lineData.text = onlinePlayerName;
        lineData.mInt = onlinePlayerPed;
        //add struct to struct list
        sub.push_back(lineData);
    }
```

but when I try to call from lines with

```
lines[i].text
```

I get "Error: Type name is not allowed".

Comment: I do not trust that cast to `LPCSTR` in the slightest.

Comment: You probably wanted to declare `vector<lines> sub;` outside of the `for()` loop.

Comment: you should post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `lines` is a `struct` (data type). `lines[i]` makes no sense. Maybe you ment `sub[i]`

Comment: WHY IS YOUR CODE SCREAMING AT ME

Comment: Be aware that **LPCSTR is a pointer and does not allocate memory**.  This means that the variable that the pointer points to must not disappear or be overwritten until the code using the pointer is finished.  This includes any other threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using the `[]` operator on a type. You declared lines as a `struct`. 
(It helps to keep to give your `typenames` a capital letter so you can differentiate them more easily.)
I think you meant to call `sub[i].text`.